# How to execute stored procedure depend on function value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a function like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[KPI](@status NUMERIC(18, 2),
                           @cardID VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @location     VARCHAR(100),
              @deltime      INT,
              @Timeintervel INT,
              @TotalTime    DATETIME,
              @currenttime  DATETIME,
              @value        INTEGER,
              @s            INT

      IF @status = 3
          OR @status = 4
        BEGIN
            SELECT @location = l.LocName
            FROM   Transaction_tbl t
                   JOIN Location_tbl l
                     ON t.Locid = l.Locid
            WHERE  t.TBarcode = @cardID

            SELECT @Timeintervel = datepart(MINUTE, l.Timeinterval)
            FROM   Location_tbl l
            WHERE  l.LocName = @location

            SELECT @deltime = datediff(MINUTE, t.Deldate, t.paydate)
            FROM   Transaction_tbl t
            WHERE  TBarcode = @cardID

            IF @deltime > @Timeintervel
              BEGIN
                  SELECT @value = @deltime - @Timeintervel
              END
            ELSE
              BEGIN
                  SELECT @value = 0
              END
        END

      RETURN @value
  END
```

I have written a stored procedure depending on this function. I want to show some details of  Tbarcode those value is greater than 0, so I have this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[KPIException] @locid     INTEGER=NULL,
                                     @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
                                     @enddate   NVARCHAR(100)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @date1 NVARCHAR(100) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @startdate + ' 00:00:00.000', 120)
      DECLARE @date2 NVARCHAR(100) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @enddate + ' 23:59:59.000', 120)

      SET NOCOUNT ON

      SELECT [dbo].[KPI](t.status, t.TBarcode) AS 'Value'
      FROM   Transaction_tbl t
      WHERE  t.dtime BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
             AND t.Locid = @locid

      IF 'value' > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT t.TBarcode AS Car_Id
            FROM   Transaction_tbl t
            WHERE  t.dtime BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
                   AND t.Locid = @locid
        END
  END
```

While executing stored procedure I am getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'value' to data
>   type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'value' > 0` is the obvious problem.

That is a string literal not a variable and a variable wouldn't cope with multiple rows anyway.

Looks like you need to replace the two `SELECT` statements with

```
  SELECT t.TBarcode 
  FROM   Transaction_tbl t
  WHERE  t.dtime BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
         AND t.Locid = @locid
         AND [dbo].[KPI](t.status, t.TBarcode) > 0
```

Performance may well be extremely poor though. Using Scalar UDFs that do data access in a `WHERE` clause is generally a recipe for unscalable code.